# Cannot install go1.20.5.windows-amd64.msi on Windows 11

Tags: go, windows-installer

I downloaded the latest Windows binary for Go from https://go.dev/dl/. This downloaded successfully as `go1.20.5.windows-amd64.msi`, file size 100,061,184 bytes.  When I try to run it, either by clicking on the file in a window, or by typing `go1.20.5.windows-amd64.msi`, I get an error message:

> This installation package could not be
> opened. Contact the application vendor to
> verify that this is a valid Windows installer
> package.

I tried running as administrator, but got the same results.  What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

- Tried double-clicking file from a window
- Tried running from a command line
- Tried running as administrator from a command line

All three resulted in exactly the same error.

Comment: What's the architecture of your system? AMD64 or ARM64? Have you checked the SHA256 Checksum to make sure the downloaded file is not corrupted? (if you have "Git for Windows", you can run `sha256sum /path/to/go1.20.5.windows-amd64.msi` in "Git Bash" to find out the SHA256 checksum.